# Changing the Default Model for Watson Language Translation

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm trying to set the default model to a trained custom model with Watson Language Translation, so when I translate for a given language pair, I don't need to specify my model.

I've tried passing `default_model` as parameter in my curl statement (all parameters correctly filled):

`curl --user apikey:{mykey} --request POST --form forced_glossary=@{mytmx} "{myurl}/v3/models?version=2018-09-28&base_model_id=es-en&name={myname}&default_model=true"`

This still creates the new model with `"default_model": false`.

I've read through the [documentation for training](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/language-translator?topic=language-translator-customizing#train-your-model) and the [API documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/language-translator/language-translator#create-model), but I don't see anything specifically pertaining to this issue.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the API documentation you will notice that `default_model` is always output, never input. ie. You can't promote a custom model to a `default_model`. Principally because it won't have all the required translations for a `default_model`.

So if you do specify it as input it will be ignored. Which means that to use the custom model in a translation you do have to specify it as `model_id`.